# localized mvc3 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to learn right approach in mvc3 localization approach. I do not want to use threads, user should select desired language and based on that value pages should be localized.

I've found [this article](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) but I want to implement localization with DRY principle.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [this article from Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx) in which he provides an overview of globalization, internationalization, and localization.

You can also give a try to the [i18n library](https://github.com/danielcrenna/i18n) on GitHub.